# I want to extract the latitude, longitude and accurency from https://mycurrentlocation.net/ using Python3 BeautifulSoup and requests modules

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, geolocation, python-requests

My basic idea is to make a simple script in order to get geographic coordinates using this site: https://mycurrentlocation.net/. 
When I run my script the attribute column is empty and the program doesn't return the list correctly : [check the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8oKAT.jpg)
Please help me! :)

```
import requests,time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

site="https://mycurrentlocation.net/"

def track_the_location():
    page=requests.get(site)
    page=bs(page.text,"html.parser")
    latitude=page.find_all("td",{"id":"latitude"})
    longitude=page.find_all("td",{"id":"longitude"})
    accuracy=page.find_all("td",{"id":"accuracy"})
    List=[latitude.text,longitude.text,accuracy.text]
    return List
print(track_the_location())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the fact, that you are running it from a local script. This behaves different from a browser as it doesn't provide any location information to the website. The needed information are provided through runtime, so you actually need to simulate a browser session to get the data as long as they don't offer an API, where you can manually specify your information.

A possible solution for that would be `selenium` as it helps you simulating a browser session. [Here's](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) the `selenium` documentation for further readings.

Hope I could help you. Have a nice day.